# Blank page with page number after list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, blank-page

I am getting a blank page after list of figures after compiling my TeX code. When I use `\clearpage` command, the page is removed but it reduces the total number of pages in my entire document. I am writing a report using report class and my references are limited to only one page if I use the `\clearpage` command otherwise the entire document is generated but with a blank page after list of figures. Can someone help me solve this issue? This is the main TeX code that I am compiling.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=15mm,bmargin=30mm,lmargin=30mm,rmargin=20mm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\onehalfspacing
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\renewcommand\bibname{Bibliography}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
  <title page contents>
\end{titlepage}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{Certificate.tex}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\input{Declaration.tex}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\input{Acknowledgement.tex}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\input{Abstract.tex} 
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\let\clearpage\relax
\input{Nomenclature.tex}
\newenvironment{mydef}[1]{\begin{definition} #1 \mbox{\\}
\rm}{\end{definition}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{Introduction.tex}
\input{Chapter1.tex}
\input{Chapter2.tex}
\input{Chapter3.tex}
\input{Conclusion.tex}
\input{Reference.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: **Do not disable `\clearpage`!** LaTeX calls `\clearpage` at the end of the document. Thus you can *miss* some page or pages at the end of the generated document. If you do  not want that chapters start at a new page, then use `\section` with document class `article` instead, for example.

Comment: I tried your code (replacing your input files by arbitrary text) and I do not get a blank page after the list of figures, whether with or without the usage of `\clearpage`. I tried with lists of figures one or two pages long. I use TeX Live on Windows7. Although this doesn't solve your problem, it might indicate that your code is fine...

Comment: Can you please tell us what you want to achieve?